# Arcgis Javascript latitude and longitude convert to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36N

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps, point

I am using Arcgis Javascript api. I have two points comes from Google maps like this

**x:**-111.67095840000002 **y:** 32.7558935

I wanna use this points on my Arcgis map. My map spatial reference is using wkt WGS_1984_UTM_Zone.... I mean it is not using wkid.

```
theX = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
theY = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

console.log("Longitude: " + theX + " Latitude: " + theY);

var pointESRI = new Point(Number(theX), Number(theY), map.spatialReference);
console.log(pointESRI);

var mp = WebMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointESRI);
console.log(mp);

pointESRI = new Point({ "x": mp.x, "y": mp.y, "spatialReference": map.spatialReference });
```

[image]

WebMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator() methot not converting point as appropriate to WGS84 reference.

Comment: When you test this, you cannot use a point in Arizona with UTM zone 36N which has usual longitude limits between +30 and +36 degrees. Esri allows a wider area, but still limited to -12 to +78.

Comment: I have tried this method WebMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator() to convert the coordinates from geographic into projected and it worked very well

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to have to use a [Geometry Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project) to project features into anything other than the Web Mercator spatial reference. This [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/util_coordinate_converter.html) show how to do a coordinate conversion using the service. The current projection [tools](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html) within the API only do a  geographic to/from Web Mercator projection.